# Java logic on fifteen minutes interval to hourly values interval calculation

Tags: java, loops, logic

I have the following variables.

1. Begindate (Date with HH:mm)
2. One price data from each begindate.

There is a price data available for every fifteen minutes starting from 00:15 to 23:45. I want to add up the price data for each hour and display them in a separate variable.

For example, For first hour, My hour 1 price = (price data of 00:15 + price data of 00:30 + price data of 00:45 and price data of 1:00) then move on to the next hour value calculation.

The same for all 24 hours. So ultimately I will have 24 values in total, each for one hour interval.

This is the code i tried.

```
for (MarketResultsView v : vs) {
     startdate = vs.gtstart()
     hourdata = startdate.getHours()
     price = vs.getPrice()
     For(int h, h<24, s++){
        if hourdata[i] = hourdata [i+1]
        then price[i]=price[i]+price[i+1]
     }
}
```

As you can see the problem here, the value of 01:00 is added to the 01:15 instead of 00:45. Also I'm not sure how to remove the price values of 00:15, 00:30 and 00:45 and keep just 01:00 in the loop.

Sorry if it shows like I've done nothing before, Im sitting here thinking very hard about the logic.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework/job for you. You write some code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, but it does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Comment: I tried using the begin date in the loop. Like, if the starting time is 1:xx then add all the values under that time.

Comment: @GowrisankarGopalakrishnan In that case, can you edit your question to include the code you said you tried?

Comment: I understand. It is not a homework, I'll paste my code here for your review soon.